# Why does intake of turbofan engine have angle of attack?

Tags: jet-engine, turbofan, inlet

As you can see the title of the question, intake of turbofan engine has an angle of attack. why? see:

[image]

Comment: Small detail: What you show in blue is not an [angle of attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_attack).